# Create custom permission level

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to organize a Document Library in Sharepoint Online in a way that the users cannot upload anything outside a determined folder structure, so they can only upload on the lowest level, however the info needs to be organized in some kind of "object" referrent to business, to go around this permission-wise i just create a template in the object level in the folder structure, which is intended for the user to copy and edit, naming it as defined by business, therefore creating a new object, all the below levels keep permission levels as they were in the template, leaving the folder structure intact.

Issue: i need to allow upload for folder level with object template, for obvious reasons, however i don't want them to upload files, only folders, so i need a custom permission level to only allow file type "Folder" or whatever to be uploaded.

I only see permission to upload or not, but can't specify what.

Anyone know how i would go about creating a permission level that lets me upload folders but not files?

Would it take a powershell script? Would it take some tweaking in .NET?

How would i go about knowing where to start looking for where to edit?
Anyone willing to point me in the right direction?

I do have some programming knowledge so i think i'm apt to do it in a timely fashion, and keep my deadline to have a completely defined Document Library ready to go live for all departments before the end of June, but i've never actually worked in any project outside school, most of my knowledge is self-taugh, and am doing this solo (cuz i'm the only one here).

Please, would you please point me at where to get documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant define specific permissions to upload folders but not files. Read more about the different permission levels here and try to apply one that closely matches what you are trying to accomplish.
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels)